# Calculate Average of last n number of weeks in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, rolling-average

I have data in which a row haa number of week and the corresponding sales on this week. Now for each week i want to calculate the average sales of last 8 weeks using DAX formula.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide us with some sample in a table or shared pbix file?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table/dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a solution posted [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Moving-Average/td-p/43041) makes use of DATESINPERIOD() and LASTDATE():

Moving_Average_3_Months = 
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX ( 'Session', 'Session'[Sessions] ),
    DATESINPERIOD (
        'Session'[FullDate],
        LASTDATE ( 'Session'[FullDate] ),
        -3,
        MONTH
    )
)

I hope this helps